# Adding new arguments to existing functions in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am building a personal R ggplot theme, but themes have some limitations, so I'm also trying to edit ggplot subfunctions in order to give them extra arguments that I want to have easy control over.

For instance, I want to take the current geom_bar() function and update it to include an option to put the count of each bar above it.

The reason I want to simply edit geom_bar() is that I want to keep my ggplot barcharts well integrated within the rest of the ggplot2 package - I just want to add some new arguments.

**I know how to define functions with optional arguments, and I know that with %+replace% I can change existing arguments, but I don't know how to add new arguments.**

Comment: `geom_bar` has a `...` argument so you can pass any argument you want already and use `trace` to add code at the relevant place.

Comment: I'm interested to understand why you wish to edit an existing function, rather than creating your own function that calls geom_bar() and the does whatever additional functionality you are seeking to add.